# Eclipse Maven Error - Failure to transfer org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:pom:2.5 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2

Tags: eclipse, maven

Im trying to create a maven project in eclipse  neon.

after creating the project, im getting the following error on the pom

```
"Failure to transfer org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:pom:2.4 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the 
 local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. 
 Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:pom:2.4 from/to central (https://
 repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection reset"
```

I did a bit of research and found the following  solution:
in cmd

- CD (change directory) to .m2\repository
- Then execute the following command for /r %i in (*.lastUpdated) do del %i
- Then update maven project dependencies

This looked like it was working but i ended up getting the same error message replaced with the value pom:2.5

I've tried repeating this process but it does not seem to be having any further effect.

i also located the file using windows explorer
in %USERPROFILE%.m2 then deleted the files that Eclipse reported as problematic

but that failed to work after updating the project

Has anyone got any other suggestions to fix this?

Comment: Network error ...proxy/firewall issue...

Comment: This is on my work machine so there could well be problems with the networt/proxy however my colleagues do not have the same issue. also Im running intellij from the same machine and have no problems creating maven projects. If this was the problem would it not have the same effect on both IDE's? Is there any steps i can follow to get past this issue.

Comment: I worked out how to fix this problem..... had to make changes to my proxy settings in the maven settings xml located in the conf file.